# Heavy updating on the ui from thread

Tags: android, multithreading, imageview

I am using Android Studios and I am currently developing an app. I have a bunch of ImageViews (approximately 30) and I want to change all of the images every second.
I have tried using a thread that will change the ImageViews but the thread did not work well. The thread gets stuck and is very slow. How can I do this without overloading the system?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you perovide code you are using to update images?

Comment: OK i wiil post the code in two comments because it is too long...

Comment: package com.example.zohar.ledbox;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Created by Zohar on 8/25/2015.
 */
public class DotsThread {
    ImageView[] Dots;
    int[] DotsColors;
    boolean stopped;
    public android.os.Handler handler;
    Random random = new Random();
    public DotsThread(Activity activity){
        Dots = new ImageView[34];
        Dots[0] = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.Dot1_1);

Comment: how can i post a code?

Comment: You can edit your post and add code there. Use special tag to make it look better

Answer (score 0):

Look into Picasso, http://square.github.io/picasso/, it will handle loading, caching, etc.